# Sine and cosine series

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $|\sin(x)| \le 1$, $|\cos(x)| \le 1$ and $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ using the power series of sine and cosine :

$$\begin{align*}
 \sin(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
\cos(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\end{align*}$$

Does anyone have an idea ? I've tried to find an upper bound for the partial sums :

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right| $$

but it seems difficult.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Homework ? If so, see this  [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) on meta discussing how to ask a homework question

Comment: Take the expansion of $e^{ix}$ and separate the real and imaginary parts, now consider the absolute value of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: @Dinesh, I guess the OP will ask how to prove the absolute value of $e^{ix}$ is $1$ **using only its power series**. Back at square one.

Comment: @Didier Piau Then I lose.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Using the power series, show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)$. Using those, show that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$.

**Added much later:** This hint has been explained in more detail in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/481218).

Furthermore, by the mean value theorem $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}\right|=|\cos(\xi)|\le1$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.

Comment: It's not a homework, I am not a student :-).
But ok, thank you for the trick !

Comment: @Selim: I gave a hint, just in case, but I think the hint is pretty easy to implement.  If you still have trouble, I will be glad to expand.

Comment: No, using the hint it's ok, thanks a lot :-)