# If we define $\sin x$ as series, how can we obtain the geometric meaning of $\sin x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In Terry Tao's textbook *Analysis*, he defines $\sin x$ as below:

> 1. Define rational numbers
> 2. Define Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, and equivalence of Cauchy sequences
> 3. Define reals as the space of Cauchy sequences of rationals modulo equivalence
> 4. Define limits (and other basic operations) in the reals
> 5. Cover a lot of foundational material including: complex numbers, power series, differentiation, and the complex exponential
> 6. Eventually (Chapter 15!) define the trigonometric functions via the complex exponential. Then show the equivalence to other definitions.

**My question** is how can we obtain the geometry interpretation of $\sin x$, that is, the ratio of opposite side and hypotenuse.

Comment: Maybe you could first notice that complex multiplication with numbers of modulus one is a rotation.

Comment: Examine the curve parameterized by $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$.

Comment: Glad to see you rewrote the question! Looks pretty popular ;P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Knowing that $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$ and that $(\sin x)'=\cos x$ (which I assume Tao proves) allows one to show that for $f(x)=\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x$, we have 
$$f'(x)=2\sin x \cos x-2\cos x\sin x =0.$$ Thus, $f$ is a constant function. Since $f(0)=1$, $f$ is identically 1.

So, the Pythagorean identity is valid:
$$
\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1.
$$
Using this, it follows that the curve $C$ parameterized by $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ is a circle of radius 1 centered at the origin. Further analysis of this curve will reveal that the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ can be read from the side lengths of right triangles.

Note, in particular that the length of arc from $t=0$ to $t=t_0$ is 
$\int_0^{t_0} \sqrt{\bigl[{dx\over dt} \bigr]^2 +\bigl[{dy\over dt}\bigr]^2 }\,dt=t_0$; so the  angle to which the "triangle method" refers is interpreted in the correct manner.

Comment: For some reason, I am seeing this for the first time now - 11 years after Calculus I! Could you verify the following? *That the sine (cosine) is the ratio of opposite (adjacent) to hypotenuse follows from the parametrization of C.*

Comment: Note   I assumed  that $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are decreasing  and increasing where they should be... Does Tao provide a proof of this?

Comment: Actually, consider the movement of a moving object generating the curve $C$. If the object came to rest at some point that is  on the circle but not on a coordinate axis, then both $(\cos t)'$ and $(\sin t)'$ would be $0$ at that point. This can't happen by the Pythagorean Identity. For $t \in\{0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2\}$ one can explicitly calculate the values of $\cos$ and $\sin$, and thus determine that the point always travels counterclockwise. Or, see @robjohn 's answer.

Comment: @DavidMitra if $t$ is point A,$t_0$ is point B.Could you prove that every point of arcAB is corresponding to $x= \cos t,y=\sin t$,$t \in [0,t_0]$

Comment: I accept this answer,but I think $\int_{\cos(\theta)}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is more intuitive.

Answer (score 13):

In [this hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78276/) I suggest showing from the power series that if
$$
\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\cos(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\tag{2}
$$
that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)$ and from there that 
$$
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ lies on the unit circle.

To see that $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ moves around the unit circle at unit speed, note that $(3)$ implies
$$
\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\cos(x),\sin(x))\right|=\left|(-\sin(x),\cos(x))\right|=1\tag{4}
$$
Thus, $(3)$ and $(4)$ say that $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ moves around the unit circle at unit speed. Note also that $(-\sin(x),\cos(x))$ is at a right angle counter-clockwise from $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$. Therefore, $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ moves counter-clockwise around the unit circle at unit speed, starting at $(1,0)$. This should be sufficient to show that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are the standard trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 10):

From the series, it is easy to see **Euler's forumla**,

$$ e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

With more series manipulation, we can obtain the Pythagorean theorem,

$$|e^{ix}| = e^{ix}e^{-ix} = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))(\cos(x) - i\sin(x)) = \cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x) = 1$$

Knowing that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have range $[-1,1]$, and are odd and even functions respectively, we see that $e^{ix}$ traces out the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. From this, we can extract the geometric interpretation of sine and cosine.

Comment: But how do you "see" that $e^{ix}$ traces out a circle from the power series definition?  And how do you show that $e^{2\pi i}=1$?  Once you have those two statements, and that $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$ for all complex $z,w$, then you can "see" that $\sin$ defined by power series is the same as $\sin$ defined "geometrically."

Comment: That's a good point, and I've tried to clarify the answer appropriately. Is it any better now?

Comment: but what does x mean,how do you establish relation of x(some real number) and $\theta$(radian)?

Answer (score 6):

To get to the geometry, take the "non-geometric" versions of cosine and sine, say $C(t)$ and $S(t)$. We can use these to parametrize the unit circle, simply because of the fact that $C^2(t)+S^2(t)=1$.

Now comes the crucial bit, calculating the *arclength*. We find that the arclength from $0$ to $t$ is $t$.  This connects $C(t)$ and $S(t)$ with "angle," which in the formal theory is just arclength.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach I've seen uses the fact that $\exp z=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{z}{n})^n$ for all complex $z$.  Then, for real $x$, we show that, for large $n$, $1+\frac{ix}{n}$, is "close enough" to $\cos \frac{x}{n} + i\sin\frac{x}{n}$, so that $(1+\frac{ix}{n})^n$ is "close enough" to $\cos x + i\sin x$.  (Here, $\cos$ and $\sin$ are the geometric definitions of the trig functions.)

So, first define $\exp z$ via the normal power series, and then show that $\exp z = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{z}{n})^n$.

Then, define $\operatorname{cis} x =\cos x + i\sin x$, and prove, using (geometric) properties of the trig functions, that $\operatorname{cis} x\operatorname{cis} y =\operatorname{cis} (x+y)$. Then note that by induction, $(\operatorname{cis} x)^n = \operatorname{cis} nx$.

Next, we are going to compute $\exp(ix)$ by writing $1+\frac{ix}n$ in polar coordiates, $r_n \operatorname{cis}(\theta_n)$.

As mentioned above, the goal is to show that, for large enough $n$, $1+\frac{ix}{n}$ is "close enough" to $\operatorname{cis} \frac{x}n$, so that the limit of $(1+\frac{ix}n)^n$ is the same as the limit of $(\operatorname{cis}\frac x n)^n = \operatorname{cis} x$, and therefore $\exp(ix)=\operatorname{cis} x$.

First, note that $r_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}}$, and show that $r_n^n\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. (This is relatively easy, noting that $(r_n)^{2n^2}\to \exp (x^2)$.)

So this shows that $\exp(ix)$ ends up on the unit circle for real $x$, and is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \operatorname{cis}(n\theta_n)$.

What we know about $\theta_n$ is that $\sin \theta_n = \frac{x}{nr_n}$.

Next you need to show is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\theta_n =  x$.  Then you've shown that $\exp(ix)=\operatorname{cis} x$.

The key to proving this last limit is to show that, for small $\theta$, $|\theta-\sin(\theta)|\leq C|\sin \theta|^2$ for some constant $C$.  Note, though, that proving this is not easy since we are assuming we do not know the power series expansion for $\sin$.

If you can show that, then you can show, for large $n$, $|\theta_n - \frac{x}{nr_n}|\leq C|\frac{x}{r_nn}|^2<C|\frac{x}{n}|^2$. So $|n\theta_n - \frac{x}{r_n}|<C\frac{|x^2|}{n}$.

So, since $\frac{x}{r_n}\to x$, $n\theta_n\to x$, and therefore, $\lim \operatorname{cis} n\theta_n = \operatorname{cis} x$

So all that's left to prove is that for small enough $\theta$, $|\theta - \sin \theta| \leq C|\sin \theta|^2$. (You could actually replace $2$ with $1+\epsilon$ for fixed $\epsilon>0$.)

The geometric reason for this last one is as follows. Let $P=(1,0)$ and $Q=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$.  Take the lines tangent to the circle at $P$ and $Q$ and let their intersection be $R$. Claims (for small $\theta>0$:)

$$|PR|=|QR|=\tan\frac{\theta}2$$
$$\sin\theta < \theta < |PR|+|QR|=2\tan\frac{\theta}2$$

The first half of the inequality is because $\sin \theta$ is the shortest distant from $Q$ to the $x$-axis, and $\theta$ is the length of the path from $Q$ to the $x$-axis along the circle.  The second inequality is a little less intuitive - basically, this is due to the rule that the shortest path from $P$ to $Q$ that does not go inside the circle is along the circle.

(For small $\theta<0$, we have to reverse all the signs, but the results are the same.)

Thus we see:

$$|\theta-\sin \theta| < |2\tan\frac\theta 2 - \sin\theta|$$

But $2\tan\frac{\theta}2 = \frac{2\sin \frac{\theta}2}{\cos\frac\theta 2}$.  Mutliply numerator and denominator by $\cos \frac{\theta}2$ and we see that:

$$2\tan\frac{\theta}2 = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\frac{\theta}2}$$

So:

$$|2\tan\frac\theta 2 - \sin\theta| = |\sin \theta \frac{\sin^2\frac \theta 2}{\cos^2\frac\theta 2}|$$

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $4\cos^2\frac \theta 2$, we get:

$$|2\tan\frac\theta 2 - \sin\theta| = |\sin\theta \frac{\sin^2\theta}{4\cos^4\frac{\theta}2}|$$

So with $\theta$ small enough that $\cos\frac\theta 2>\frac{1}{2}$, we have

$$|\theta-\sin \theta| < |2\tan\frac\theta 2 - \sin\theta| < 4|\sin^3\theta|<4|\theta|^3$$

So we now know that $\exp ix = \operatorname{cis} x$.  That means, in turn, that $$\sin x = \frac{\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)}{2i}$$ and $$\cos x = \frac{\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)}{2}$$

From there we can derive the power series for $\sin$ and $\cos$ using the power series for $\exp$.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula (the complex exponential) and the identification of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ does that for us. Then the equations $x=\cos\theta,~y=\sin\theta$ define the ordinate and abscissa of points on the unit circle; drawing in the relevant triangles gets you the rest of the way.

From the series definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$, the easiest link with geometry is via the complex exponential series to derive Euler's formula, $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$. Once we have that, the rest follows (from the background that Tao provides).