# How would I go about showing $\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, binomial-theorem

I want to look at the summation for both cos,sin..

$cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...= \sum\nolimits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$
so, $cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^{2n}}{(2n)!}$. So how I need to expand $(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^{2n}$ using the binomial formula maybe?

I want to look at manipulating the POWER series specifically for proving this identity.

Comment: Taylor series is certainly the hard way to prove the result in the title.

Comment: I depends on your definitions.

Comment: This will help me build some intuition on how to show, $\cos(x+y)=cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y)$. Specifically by manipulating the power series.

Comment: Do you know (in the sense that you allow yourself to use the fact) that $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$ and $\sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$?

Comment: Actually, using the power series, I think the general addition theorem is easier to show than this specific instance.

Comment: As an exercise and tour de force, showing this with power series can be nice (for some...I guess...). If you want to go highschoolish use the good' ol trigonometric circle and the basic definitions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from $$\cos(x+\pi/2) = \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n \frac{(x+\pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$
Now ask yourself about the coefficient of $x^k$ in this series, it is given by
$$\sum_{2n\ge k} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{2n}{k} (\pi/2)^{2n-k}
= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{2n\ge k} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-k)!} (\pi/2)^{2n-k}.$$
In this last series the $2n-k$ term starts at zero when $k$ is even and is given by
$$\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{q+k/2}}{(2q)!} (\pi/2)^{2q}
= \frac{(-1)^{k/2}}{k!} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^q}{(2q)!} (\pi/2)^{2q} =
\frac{(-1)^{k/2}}{k!} \cos(\pi/2) = 0.$$
When $k$ is odd  the $2n-k$ term starts at one and is given by
$$\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{q+(k+1)/2}}{(2q+1)!} (\pi/2)^{2q+1}
\\= \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)/2}}{k!} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^q}{(2q+1)!} (\pi/2)^{2q+1}
= \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)/2}}{k!} \sin(\pi/2) = \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)/2}}{k!}.$$
It follows that
$$\cos(x+\pi/2) = \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(2m+1)!} x^{2m+1} = -\sin(x).$$

Comment: Congratulations to @robjohn who was faster than me by half a minute.

Comment: I get it, I did see it half a minute before I posted but the date stamp says five minutes. ;-) Tough luck for me I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't worry. I don't think any of these answers will get a windfall of votes :-) Not that they are not good, it's just that some topics attract a lot more voters.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\binom{2k}{j}x^j(\pi/2)^{2k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\binom{2k}{j}x^j(\pi/2)^{2k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-j)!j!}x^j(\pi/2)^{2k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-j)!}(\pi/2)^{2k-j}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that when $j$ is even,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-j)!}(\pi/2)^{2k-j}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+j/2}}{(2k)!}(\pi/2)^{2k}\\
&=(-1)^{j/2}\cos(\pi/2)\\[12pt]
&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that when $j$ is odd,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-j)!}(\pi/2)^{2k-j}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+(j+1)/2}}{(2k+1)!}(\pi/2)^{2k+1}\\
&=(-1)^{(j+1)/2}\sin(\pi/2)\\[12pt]
&=(-1)^{(j+1)/2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging $(2)$ and $(3)$ back into $(1)$, removing the even terms and reindexing the odd terms, yields
$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)
&=-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!}x^{2j+1}\\
&=-\sin(x)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: See my answer for a less painful approach using the special values. +1

Answer (score 2):

What you sketch there is definitely the hard way to do this. When you expand the binomials, each of them will contribute terms to *every* term of lower degree in the resulting series, and then you have to sum all of these to find the coefficients.

It's much easier (not to mention more instructive) to follow the programs outlined in answers to [How to prove periodicity of sin(x) or cos(x) starting from the Taylor series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how).

Comment: @henning..I'm sorry I edited it and meant to say power series.

Comment: @3.1416: Whether you call them power series or Taylor series doesn't change the fact that it's the hard way to do it. (Nor does it change the relevance of the question I link to).

Comment: It actually works out pretty nicely, if you assume that $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=1$

Answer (score 2):

As an example, one can use the statement that

> **PROP** If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''+f=0$, then $f=0$.

**P** The ODE gives $f'f''+ff'=0$, so that $(f')^2+f^2=K$. But then $K=0$ from the initial conditions. This gives that $f=0$.

> **COR** If $f(0)=a,f'(0)=b$ and $f''+f=0$ then $f=a\cos+b\sin$.

**P** Set $g=a\cos +b\sin $. Then $h=f-g$. It follows $h''+h=0$ and $h(0)=0,h'(0)=0$ so $h\equiv 0$ by the lemma.

(*Giveaway*: let $f(x)=\cos (x+y)-\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y$ in the first result, or $f(x)=\cos (x+y)$ in the corrollary)

Then you can prove that $\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$ using the above, letting $y$ be a constant.

Alternatively, let $f=\sin x+\cos \left(x+\dfrac \pi 2\right)$ above. You will need to use the special values $\sin \dfrac \pi 2=1$ and $\cos \dfrac\pi 2=0$, though. One can in fact define $\dfrac \pi 2$ to be the unique number determined by $$\inf\{x>0:\cos x=0\}$$

Comment: @robjohn One can prove it with the above, that's the point of it. To compute the derivatives is usual business, what do you mean?

Comment: Okay. I agree. It looks as if you are assuming too much, but since the series gives you $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)$, you only need to know $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ and $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ to get the rest.

Comment: In effect, this uses the power series, but I'm not sure I would classify it as manipulating the power series. +1 for the concise (if a bit terse) presentation.

Comment: @robjohn Heh, thanks. Terse? What do you mean? =O

Comment: As a proof, it shows everything it needs to. As an explanation, it is a bit short. Just an opinion.